# why bash script default case statement always executed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I wrote a bash script that reads script arguments and pass them to parsearg function:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function main() {
    parseargs2 "$@"
}

function parseargs2() {
    MAINCOMMAND=$1
    shift
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        case $1 in
            -s|--service) SERVICE_NAME="$2" ;;
            -r|--registry) REGISTRY="$2" ;;
            -h|--help) HELP=true ;;
            *) echo "help" && exit 1;;
        esac
        shift
    done
    echo "SERVICE_NAME: $SERVICE_NAME"
    echo "REGISTRY: $REGISTRY"
    echo "HELP: $HELP"
    echo "cmd: $MAINCOMMAND"
}

main "$@"
```

now when I run my script it always executes help command and then exits, I don't know why it will be ok when I remove `*)` case

```bash
./example.sh build --service api --registry dockerhub
```

EDIT:
thanks to @chepner comment I found the problem I solved this by adding `shift 2` at end of while loop

Comment: You see `--service`, you set `SERVICE_NAME`, but then you only remove *one* argument. The next iteration of the loop checks if `api` is a defined option, and it's not. You have to remove `api` as well before you check the value of `$1` again.

Comment: @markp-fuso thank you for your comment, It's for debugging right? The `MAINCOMMAND` is actually a subcommand it could be `build` or `release` in this case it's `build`

Comment: @chepner thank you for quick reply I found that thnaks I added `shift 2` instead of `shift` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Doing your own option parsing is a little fraught, but the idea should be to do an extra `shift` whenever you have an argument:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    case $1 in
        -s|--service) SERVICE_NAME="$2" ; shift;;
        -r|--registry) REGISTRY="$2" ; shift;;
        -h|--help) HELP=true ;;
        *) echo "help" && exit 1;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

You may or may not want to support a style where the single-letter version of an option has its argument jammed up against it, which works in many stock programs:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    case $1 in
        -s|--service) SERVICE_NAME="$2" ; shift;;
        -s*) SERVICE_NAME=${1#-s};;
        -r|--registry) REGISTRY="$2" ; shift;;
        -r*) REGISTRY=${1#-r};;
        -h|--help) HELP=true ;;
        *) echo "help" && exit 1;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

Also, there's no reason to name your variables in all-caps. All caps is usually a sign that a variable is being `export`ed into the environment so some other program you're going to run can see it; otherwise, just use lowercase. Additionally, you don't need quotation marks on the right-hand side of an assignment, and if you're really using `bash` (rather than some other POSIX type shell), you likely want to use `((`...`))` for numeric comparisons.

```
help=   # don't assume variables aren't set on entry
maincommand=$1
shift
while (( $# )); do
    case "$1" in
        -s|--service) service_name=$2 ; shift;;
        -s*) service_name=${1#-s};;
        -r|--registry) registry=$2 ; shift;;
        -r*) registry=${1#-r};;
        -h|--help) help=true ;;
        *) echo "help" && exit 1;;
    esac
    shift
done
for var in service_name registry help maincommand; do
   printf '%s: "%s"\n' "$var" "${!var}"
done
```

FWIW, `true` is just a string to the shell with no special significance; the shell doesn't have Boolean values beyond "command succeeded/failed" (which is just zero/nonzero on the exit code) or Boolean operators other than the ones that operate on commands (e.g. `command1` && `run this if command1 succeeded`). So when flags are stored in shell variables the Booleanness is usually represented  either by empty vs. nonempty string (and `true` is a fine value to use for the nonempty case) or 0 vs. 1 (or 0 vs nonzero) number.